# Typescript "error a constructor method accessor or property was expected" error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm new to typescript. In this problem I need to increase the counter of "setBigCar" or "setSmallCar" when the "carSmall" is false or the other way around then display it on my browser

```
  const pageHeader = (
  <PageHeader
    style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", marginTop: 4 }}
    title="Car Management - Admin"  
     <span>{`Big Car: `}</span>, //not sure how to display it
      <span>{`Small Car : `}</span>, 
  />
);

function setTotalBoth { //error a constructor method accessor or property was expected

var setBigCar = 0;
var setSmallCar = 0;

if(carSmallCar == false) { setBigCar +1 } 

else { setSmallCar +1}

};
```

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pageHeader = (
  <PageHeader
    style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", marginTop: 4 }}
    title="Car Management - Admin"
  >
    <span>{`Big Car: `}</span>, //not sure how to display it
    <span>{`Small Car : `}</span>, 
  <PageHeader/>
);
```